# Не удается установить связь между сущностью и коллекциями

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Есть класс пользователя VKUser, который будет наполняться данными через Oauth2, у класса имеется несколько строковых полей и поле класса VKFriendsList, который содержит список `ArrayList<VKUser>` пользователей-друзей подписчика.
Класс пользователя:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VK_profile")
public class VKUser implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long profile_id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Long user_id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
    private Integer age;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "friends_list_id")
    private VKFriendsList vkfriends;
```

Фрэндлист:

```
@Entity
public class VKFriendsList {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "vkfriends")
    private ArrayList<VKUser> friends_list;
```

По идее, у каждого пользователя может быть только один фрэндлист, и один фрэндлист может быть только у одного пользователя.
При запуске вылетает исключение, никак не могу его исправить что бы ни делал, думаю, что ошибка где то в логике связей, но никак не могу понять где именно, нет опыта

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: mybase.entities.vk.VKFriendsList.friends_list, referenced property unknown: java.util.ArrayList.vkfriends
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1664) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Comment: Похоже что у каждого пользователя может быть несколько листов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае стоит покопать в направлении связи "многие ко многим". Для списка друзей не нужна отдельная сущность. Пример:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VK_profile")
public class VKUser implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long profile_id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Long user_id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String city;
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="vk_friends",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friendId")
    )
    private List<VKUser> friends; // дружит с

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="vk_friends",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friendId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userId")
    )
    private List<VKUser> friendOf; // является другом для
    //....
}
```